# Serverless functions on Vercel not writing to database with prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, serverless, prisma, vercel

Hello I am new to the whole serverless concept, I created my own wedding site because I'm hard headed and thought that I could create a better one then the free one offered by the knot. So I used Next.js for this project and created a form for people to RSVP. This form then posts react state objects to the API route 'api/rsvp' where I have a function to write the data to a planetscale MySql database. This function works perfectly fine locally but when I deployed the project to Vercel it no longer saved the data to the database.

Here is my API route code, am I doing anything wrong?

```
import prisma from '../../lib/prisma';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { first, last, attending, email, meal, kids } = req.body;
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        try {
            const createGuest = await prisma.guest.create({
                data: {
                    first: first,
                    last: last,
                    attending: attending,
                    email: email,
                    meal: meal,
                    kids: kids
                }
            })
            res.status(202).json({ success: createGuest})
        } catch(error) {
            res.status(403).json({ dberror: error})
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404)
    }
}
```